# Kaplan-Meier by strata in survminer, but the risk table not by strata

Tags: r, ggplot2, survminer

I am creating a KM plot using `survminer`:

```
survfit(Surv(tte, event) ~ trt, data = data) %>%
  ggsurvplot(
    risk.table = TRUE,
    risk.table.pos = "in"
  )
```

This gives a KM curve split by `trt`, but the risk table is also split by `trt` too. Is there a way that I can just have the total number across all groups in the risk table, but keep the strata for the plot it's self?

Answer (score 0):

As `ggsurvplot` object is basically a list containing the plot of the survival curve as an element named `plot` and the risk table as an element `table`. Hence, one option to achieve your desired result would be to creat two `ggsurvplot` object, one stratified by group, one for both or all groups. Afterwards you could take the `plot` element from the first and the `table` element from the second.

Using the default example from `?ggsurvplot`:

```r
library(survminer)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
#> Loading required package: ggpubr
library(survival)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'survival'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:survminer':
#> 
#>     myeloma

plot <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung) |> 
  ggsurvplot(
    risk.table = TRUE,
    risk.table.pos = "in"
  )

table <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = lung) |> 
  ggsurvplot(
    risk.table = TRUE,
    risk.table.pos = "in",
    palette = "blue"
  )

plot$plot <- plot$plot
plot$table <- table$table

plot
```

[image]